# Converting multiple string lines and reading each line as an integer

Tags: python

line.read contains

```
25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32.33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40.25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32.33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40.25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32.33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40.25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32.33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40
```

My single line reader is here

```
output = open('line.read', 'r')  # See the r
nodes_list = output.read().strip().split('.')
mylist = [[int(cell) for cell in row.split(',')] for row in nodes_list]
```

My output is in this code.

```
['25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32', '33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40', '25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32', '33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40', '25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32', '33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40', '25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32', '33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40']
```

This code reads only one line however i want to read multiple lines and convert it to 8x8 integer array. Old value is not important for me. I just want to read current line. How can i do that ? It will read first line it will do smth after that it will look second line etc.

My txt will be something like this

```
25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32.33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40.25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32.33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40.25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32.33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40.25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32.33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40
22,33,21,33,40,37,24,23.15,13,12,35,33,12,15,23.22,33,21,33,40,37,24,23.15,13,12,35,33,12,15,23.22,33,21,33,40,37,24,23.15,13,12,35,33,12,15,23.22,33,21,33,40,37,24,23.15,13,12,35,33,12,15,23
...
```

I can find it by looking empty cell or i can put a special character to my txt file which can know end of the line. However, If i do this, it will read it as an string and also it shows all value. It should do that line by line. Thanks for helping

Comment: The output you are getting is already a 8x8 matrix, the one line is just the representation which you can change by printing it differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although it is not abundantly clear to me, but I think this is what you are looking for.

```
with open('test.txt','r') as fout:
    line = fout.readline()
    while line:
        a = [[int(col) for col in row.split(',')] for row in line.split('.')]
        print(a)
        #Do something with your list a
        line = fout.readline()
```

Output for the print() function:

```
[[25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32], [33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40], [25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32], [33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40], [25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32], [33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40], [25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32], [33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40]]
[[22, 33, 21, 33, 40, 37, 24, 23], [15, 13, 12, 35, 33, 12, 15, 23], [22, 33, 21, 33, 40, 37, 24, 23], [15, 13, 12, 35, 33, 12, 15, 23], [22, 33, 21, 33, 40, 37, 24, 23], [15, 13, 12, 35, 33, 12, 15, 23], [22, 33, 21, 33, 40, 37, 24, 23], [15, 13, 12, 35, 33, 12, 15, 23]]
```

And last but not least, there's no array in the core Python library. Always say List when you mean array.